# I don’t understand how @if statements work in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I started learn Laravel and ran into an @if statements problem. How must I write a condition for empty places of code so that it is correct?

```
@if( !Request::is('coming-soon') )

@elseif( !Request::is('error') )

@else
    @include('layouts.includes.header.main-menu')
@endif
```

I don't need this view in 'coming-soon' and 'error' pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it opposite:

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
@if( !Request::is('coming-soon') && !Request::is('error') )
    @include('layouts.includes.header.main-menu')
@endif
```

This will include the page if the requested url is not "coming-soon" or "error".

Comment: i getting none errors.. but if i writing one conditional this working

Comment: Ok i updated my answer now. I changed OR to AND. Try now

Comment: thank you very much. it is working now! but i thought that this work when all of  conditional is true but not only one of all